# I can't open Python in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I was going through the setup section of "Learn Python the hard way" and I can't seem to open Python in Powershell. I have tried the command in the book:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
```

and when I click enter it does nothing. I have also tried:

```
$env:path="$env:Path;C:\Python27"
```

but it also does nothing. I did `START python` but that doesn't start python on PowerShell. What should I do?

Comment: What you're typing does not attempt to start Python. It simply adds the folder where Python was installed to the user's PATH. Keep reading.

Comment: After having run the above command, re-open powershell and type `python` and then hit enter

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen wow. Thanks for the info... it worked!